# Trim first word to 3 characters in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to split a word like `September 4` down to `Sep 4` and I'm not sure how I'd go about that.

The dom I'm trying to edit looks like this:

```
<div>
   <p>September 1</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>Date</p>
   <p>September 2</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>Date</p>
   <p>September 3</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>Date</p>
   <p>September 4</p>
</div>
```

I figure I can edit the `p` tag I want by doing: `$("div p:nth-child(2)").text()` but I'm not sure how to trim the first word to just 3 characters.. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function that processes the current text in your p-element and let it return the modified text. It would look something like this:

```
$("div p:nth-child(2)").text(function(i, oldtext) {
  var splitArray = oldtext.split(" ");
  return splitArray[0].substr(0,3) + " " + splitArray[1];
});
```

Comment: It lacks the closing bracket and the semicolon at the very end.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do that, split the words into an array (separate by space), then remove the characters off the first word, finally join the array again and add the spaces back:

```
function trimFirstWord(text, amount) {
    var wordArray = text.split(" ");
    wordArray[0] = wordArray[0].substring(0, amount);
    wordArray = wordArray.join(" ");
    return wordArray;
}

// Will be "Sep 4"
var newText = trimFirstWord("September 4", 3);
```

Then here is how you would implement that with `.text()`:

```
$("div p:nth-child(2)").text(function(){ 
    return trimFirstWord($(this).text(), 3) 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.text(function(index, text){})` , `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/(^[a-z]{3})|(\s\d+)/gi`

```js
$("div p:nth-child(2)").text(function(_, txt) {
  return txt.match(/(^[a-z]{3})|(\s\d+)/gi).join("");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
   <p>September 1</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>Date</p>
   <p>September 2</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>Date</p>
   <p>September 3</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>Date</p>
   <p>September 4</p>
</div>
```